# overfull hbox there's no line here to end

Tags: hyperref, lists

Hello im noob in here and programing xtex and general, i need help with this.
I just want create a list with, Text, URL, Text

i already have(Original problem in : "entrylist"):

```
 \documentclass[]{cv}
    \usepackage{afterpage}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \hypersetup{
        pdftitle={},
        pdfauthor={},
        pdfsubject={},
        pdfkeywords={},
        colorlinks=false,       % no lik border color
       allbordercolors=white    % white border color for all
    }
    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
    \RequirePackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{pblue}{HTML}{0395DE}

    \begin{document}

    \header{text}{123}  

    \begin{entrylist} 
~ {text: \href{web link}{text}}\\ 
~ {text: \href{web link}{text}}\\ 
\end{entrylist}

    \end{document}
```

THX for fast response, im gona prove that

Sorry, rules dont let me edit my post if is short, i hope this dont get me banned, sorry bad inglish.
I add some extra info, i have in doc.

Comment: So where do get access to `cv.cls`? we would need that in order to recreate your problem. What type of CV are you creating? Friggeri?

Comment: i have an exemple, sorry cant pass link cus im noob and rules dont let me post url, but you can search in google: extended fancy cv, im using that.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're look to create a generic list of some sort, with items that contain some text as well as a hyperlink.

Lists are easily obtained using either `itemize` or `enumerate` (customizations are possible, of course, with or without packages) while hyperlinks are implemented using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Text A: \href{http://www.google.ca}{Google}
  \item Text B: \href{http://tex.stackexchange.com}{TeX.SE}
  \item Text C: \href{http://ctan.org}{CTAN}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```